# Set multiple time in cron setup

Tags: cron

I want to set cron at 3am, 5am & 7am MST. How should we set multiple times in one cron setup?

From the net I got to know that there are 5 stars. * * * * *
Each of having different meaning.
First star is minute
Second star is hour 
Third star is day of month
Fourth star is month.
Fifth star is day of week.

By this means should it be like this - 
* 3,5,7 * * *

Does it correct?

Comment: please try to generate this online tool https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Comment: Well... Maybe try first?

Comment: ```0 0 3,5,7 ? * * *``` your answer

Answer (score 0):

No, this will not work. You need to create three cronjobs
1) 0 3 * * * /path/to/your/script
2) 0 5 * * * /path/to/your/script
3) 0 7 * * * /path/to/your/script